# Displaying custom post type on front page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, homepage

I added a new custom post type to my Wordpress theme but it refuses to show on the homepage. I tried setting

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'post_type' => array('post', 'reviews') ) );?>
```

but it doesn't seem to work, it just loops my normal posts. Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Here's a pastie of my index if anyone wants to see it:

http://pastie.org/5120964

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your question to make answers possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid the use of query_posts -- it forces another database hit.  There are plenty of other ways to hook  in and change the query before posts are fetches.  `pre_get_posts` is one of them.

To display multiple post types on the home page (pages and posts in this example):

```
<?php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse70606_pre_posts');
/**
 * Change that query! No need to return anything $q is an object passed by 
 * reference {@link http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php}.
 *
 * @param   WP_Query $q The query object.
 * @return  void
 */
function wpse70606_pre_posts($q)
{
    // bail if it's the admin, not the main query or isn't the (posts) page.
    if(is_admin() || !$q->is_main_query() || !is_home())
        return;

    // whatever type(s) you want.
    $q->set('post_type', array('post', 'page'));
}
```

This would go in your themes's `functions.php` file or [in a plugin](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/pages-on-home.php).

Comment: Can you better explain where I would put this? In the index, loop, or functions?

Comment: see my edit: in functions (probably sans the open `<?php` or in a plugin.

Comment: Can we show postype name or label as headings on frontend?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this first:

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'any',
) );

query_posts( $args );
```

This will keep the original query, and display every single post (-1 means "all posts"), of every post type. That should help you troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Where would this go? Into the loop or into index?

Comment: `get_posts()` would be better, because `query_posts()` will overwrite the main query object.